# 'UserContextProvider' is not defined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

**src/contexts/user.js**

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
export const UserContext= createContext();
export const UserContextProvider= (props)=>{
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
//const [name, setName] = useState(null);
return (
<UserContext.Provider value={{user: [user, setUser] }}>
            {props.children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
};
```

**src/components/signin-btn/index.js**

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import "./style.css"
import { UserContext } from '../../contexts/user';
import { signInWithGoogle } from '../../services/auth';
import "./style.css";
export default function SignInBtn() {
//const [user, setuser] = useState(SignInBtn) {
const[user,setUser] = useContext(UserContext).user;

const signInBtnClick = async() => {
let userBySignIn = await signInWithGoogle();
if(userBySignIn) setUser(userBySignIn);
        };
return (
<div className="signInBtn">

            <p>Sign in with Google</p>

        </div>
    );
}
```

**src/App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Home} from './pages';
function App() {
return (
<UserContextProvider>
      <div className="App">
      <Home />
      </div>
    </UserContextProvider>
  );
}
export default App;
```

> Error Failed to compile. src\App.js Line 8:6: 'UserContextProvider' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

***Am I missing something?***

Answer (score 1):

`App.js` is missing the following line:

```js
import { UserContextProvider } from './contexts/user';
```